Implications of an Isometric Adjoint Operator in Banach Space
Let $E$ and $F$ be two Banach spaces. Let $T: E \to F$ be a linear continuous operator, and suppose that its adjoint $T'$ is isometric.
It is known that since $T'$ is lower bounded, $T$ is surjective. It is also known that we cannot say in general that $T$ is also isometric: Adjoint operator on Banach space
Does the fact that $T'$ is isometric have a more precise implication on $T$ than simply $T$ being surjective?

Does this help?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247582/adjoint-operator-on-banach-space?rq=1

@ChrisEagle Thank you! I add a clarification thanks to your comment.
